# HTTPS POST request is not passing any data

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, https, request

I am trying to replay a request to another instance of my API, so I am making a POST request as shown below. This works fine except for the fact that the data (`JSON.stringify(req.body)`) is not being passed. `req.body` on the other instance returns a blank map `{}` even though I have confirmed that `JSON.stringify(req.body)` returns what I expect. Is there something wrong with how I am passing the data with the POST request? Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
  var betaReq = https.request({
    hostname: 'some-product-beta.cloudfunctions.net',
    path: '/intercomEventsReplayed',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'x-hub-signature': req.headers['x-hub-signature']
    }
  });
  betaReq.write(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  betaReq.end();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your post request. This: _This works fine except for the fact that the data (JSON.stringify(req.body)) is not being passed._ is probably inaccurate. It is being passed, otherwise you would see an error. More likely, it is not resolving to what you want it to. Presumably this is an empty object `{}` that you identified? In other words, `'{}'` is what is being written as the request body?

Comment: Have you tried adding "Content-type": "appplication/json" to your headers?

Comment: did you install body parser?